# C# console application onKeyUp

Tags: c#

I've been trying to make a small game in the Console Application within Visual Studio. I want detect when I let go of a key. Because now when i let go of the key it stays "true" until i hit any other key.

Here is my code,

```
while (true)
{
    keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();

    if(keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
    {
         rightPressed = true;
    } else
    {
         rightPressed = false;
    }
}
```

Does someone have a solution?

Comment: Looks like there is no solution for key up event on console applications. You should go with Forms. Otherwise you should workaround your logic of key up events function.